# KSQL Stream Json (string) word with the value

Tags: json, apache-kafka, ksqldb

i have this record in the topic:

```
{“ACCOUNT_TYPE_KY”:“7”,“ADDED_BY”:“f_affina”,CDC_TIMESTAMP":{“string”:“2023-07-19T16:43:44.926000000000”}}
```

why i got this (string) with the value and how can i get rid with it while creating the stream and use the new topic in the connector?

i already created the following streams:

```
CREATE STREAM CORTEX_TYPE (ACCOUNT_TYPE_KY VARCHAR KEY, ADDED_BY VARCHAR, } CDC_TIMESTAMP VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC=‘arb.snpdh_CTX_ACCOUNT_TYPE’, VALUE_FORMAT=‘JSON’);

CREATE STREAM CORTEX_TYPE_STREAM WITH(VALUE_FORMAT=‘AVRO’) AS SELECT * FROM CORTEX_TYPE;
```

and used CORTEX_TYPE_STREAM in the sink connector and it worked but the field CDC_TIMESTAMP has the value -->

```
string":"2023-07-19T16:43:44.926000000000
```

i want the value only without string.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the data isn't Avro? The type `string` key comes from JSON Avro Encoding - https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#json-encoding

You got it because the producer sent it; ksqlDB does not add random fields to your existing topics. You will want to adjust your producer code.